# Inline debugging in ASP.NET VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have an VB.NET application with few functions i need to debug (like ie. Assert in C#). Is it possible and how i do that ?

```
    Public Shared Function createNumberArrayList(ByVal startValue As Integer, _
                                             ByVal endValue As Integer, _
                                             Optional ByVal isBackwards As Boolean = False) As ArrayList
    Dim nArrayList As New ArrayList()
    If Not isBackwards Then
        For index As Integer = startValue To endValue
            nArrayList.Add(index)
        Next
    Else
        For index As Integer = endValue To startValue
            nArrayList.Add(index)
        Next
    End If
    Return nArrayList
End Function
```

Basically what i need is to enter few values and see if the function works and returns proper ArrayList.

Thanks

Comment: Ugh, don't use ArrayList in .Net 2.0 and later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assert is not specific to C#, it's a framework method, so it can be used in any .NET language. You can do something like this:

```
Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(nArrayList.Count > 0)
```

**Edit:**

I'm not sure whether Debug.Assert works in ASP.NET applications or not, I found contradictory info on the web about this... If it doesn't work, [check out this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/debuglistener.aspx).

Comment: How do i check this ? I mean how do i make VS to execute Debug.Assert ? Sorry for noobness

Comment: Just add asserts in your code, then run your website in debug, and it will show a popup if an Assert fails. If it doesn't... check my edit.

Comment: It will write a message in the Output window by default.